# How to declare a Swift Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to figure out my errors in a swift program it is my first program in swift and I'm learning the syntax.  How would one declare an array in swift?

Comment: Please read apple docs. & follow tutorials at web first. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: thanks! very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Try

```
 var temp = [Int]()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to declare an array in Swift there are two ways.  The most popular and most idiomatic is to use square brackets around a type.  For an Array of Ints you might have:

```
var myArrayOfInts : [Int]
```

This is syntax sugar for using the generic `Array` struct so you could equivalently write:

```
var myArrayOfInts : Array<Int>
```

Though I don't believe I have ever seen that written in any code (after the square bracket syntax was introduced) in any case that wasn't an example (just like this one) of how the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple

```
var myArray: [String] = []
```